# Variadic parameters for routes in ExpressJS

Tags: express

Is it possible to have variadic parameters for routes in Express?

Such as:

app.get("/:foo/(*:bar)", (req, res) => {

and a GET is requested for http://hostname/a/b/c/d

// foo = "a"
// bar = ["b", "c", "d"]